# Algorithm to calculate the start day of the next month

Tags: c++, time, calendar

I am writing a simple calendar class. I am trying to overload `operator++` to use it to move the calendar to the next month. However, my algorithm to find the next month's start day is not quite right.

```
calendar calendar::operator ++(int)
{
   int hold;
   calendar cal = *this;

   month++;
   if (month > December)
   {
      month = January;
      year++;
      if (year == 0)
         year++;
   }
   previousStartDay = startDay;
   startDay = nextStartDay;
   nextStartDay = findNextStartDay();
   return cal;
}

int calendar::findNextStartDay() const
{
   int monthLength,
       day = startDay;

   monthLength = findMonthLength(false);
   monthLength -= 28;
   day += monthLength;
   if (day > Saturday)
      day -= Saturday;
   return day;
}
```

January is defined as 0, December is 11, Sunday is 0, Saturday is 6. startDay, previousStartDay, nextStartDay, month, and year are all private class variables

When I test this for 2013, the dates are correct until march. At which point it gives the next start day as Tuesday instead of Monday.

I also tried this:

```
int calendar::findNextStartDay() const
{
   int monthLength,
       day = startDay;

   monthLength = findMonthLength(false);
   monthLength -= 28;
   day -= monthLength;
   if (day < Sunday)
      day += Saturday;
   return day;
}
```

however, it also gives the same results.

**EDIT:**

I am accounting for leap years. Here is my code from `findMonthLength()` to determine if it is or not.

```
if ((!(year % 4) && (year % 100)) || !(year % 400))
   monthLength = 29;
else
   monthLength = 28;
```

Comment: Start day of March 2012 was Thursday?

Comment: You say the result is wrong in march.  February is the month with weird leap day rules.  hmmm

Comment: Sorry I meant 2013. Correcting now...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Comment: @brian beuning I am correcting for leap years when I find the month length. It also gets an farther off as it keeps going. In April it gives the next month's start day as Sunday, when it is Wednesday.

Comment: unless this is homework: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem analysis

Let's assume we are in March and you have the correct start day (Friday, 5).

Your `findNextStartDay` algorithm will find `monthlength` equal to 3 (31-28), then day will be 2 (8 - 6), which is Tuesday (2) instead of Monday (1)...

Let's see why this is wrong by running the algorithm (first version of `findNextStartDay`):

**January**: 31-28 = 3, day = 2 (Tuesday) + 3 = 5 (Friday), which is the correct start date of February.

**February**: 28 - 28 = 0, day = 5 (Friday) + 0 = 5 (Friday), which is the correct start date of March.

**March**: 31-28 = 3, day = 5 (Friday) + 3 - 6 (Saturday) = 2 (Tuesday), which is the wrong start date of April.

## Bug Explanation

The problem is that when you subtract Saturday to a result in overflow (more than Saturday),  you are leaving one day out of the count (i.e.: you subtract one day less than what you want).

Think of the case in which you end up with `day == 7`. You would want to have Sunday (one more than Saturday - circularly increased), then you have to remove 7, not 6, otherwise you will get Monday!

The error is in the circular increment: in a correct algorithm 1 beyond 6 (i.e. 7) must go back to 0, 2 beyond 6 (i.e. 8) must go back to 1 and so on.

In your algorithm 1 beyond 6 (i.e. 7) goes back to 1, leaving out the poor 0 (Sunday) and making one day of the week disappear each time you end up in this case.

If you subtract `Saturday + 1` you get the right day of the next month in case of "week days overflow".

## Bug Fixing

In short, change this line:

```
day -= Saturday;
```

to

```
day -= (Saturday + 1);
```

But please, consider reviewing your code to a cleaner version of the algorithm!

A small tip is to use the modulo operator to do the circular addition:

```
day = ((day + monthlength) % (Saturday + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

boost gives you couple of nice [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html). Here I implemented `boost::gregorian` based on one from examples. This code takes year, month and prints date and day of week of the first day of next month:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    using namespace boost::gregorian;

    greg_year year(1400);
    greg_month month(1);

    // get a month and a year from the user
    try {
      int y, m;
      std::cout << "   Enter Year(ex: 2002): ";
      std::cin >> y;
      year = greg_year(y);
      std::cout << "   Enter Month(1..12): ";
      std::cin >> m;
      month = greg_month(m);
    }
    catch(bad_year by) {
      std::cout << "Invalid Year Entered: " << by.what() << '\n'
        << "Using minimum values for month and year." << std::endl;
    }
    catch(bad_month bm) {
      std::cout << "Invalid Month Entered" << bm.what() << '\n'
        << "Using minimum value for month. " << std::endl;
    }

    // create date and add one day to the end of month
    date d(year, month, 1);
    d=(year,month,d.end_of_month());
    date_duration dd(1);
    d += dd;
    // print date
    std::cout << d << " " << d.day_of_week() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

> Enter Year(ex: 2002): 2013
>
> Enter Month(1..12): 3
>
> 2013-Apr-01 Mon
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6s)

---

using `std::vector`:

```
boost::gregorian::date d1(2013,boost::gregorian::Jan,31);
boost::gregorian::date d2(2013,boost::gregorian::Feb,28);
boost::gregorian::date d3(2013,boost::gregorian::Mar,31);

std::vector<boost::gregorian::date > v;
v.push_back(d1);
v.push_back(d2);
v.push_back(d3);

boost::gregorian::date_duration duration(1);

for(std::vector<boost::gregorian::date >::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++){
    *it+=duration;
    std::cout << *it <<" "<< (*it).day_of_week() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @kennycoc is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: This is nice, but I'd rather use my own algorithm. If I wasn't just starting out programming I would probably use this, but I think I will learn faster if I struggle through finding algorithms myself first.

Comment: If you're learning that seems fine.  But I have to say: don't roll your own in any project you intend to share with anyone.  There be dragons... you really really want to leverage a solid library like boost in C++ or moment in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the february because this month can have 29 or 28 day(depends if the year is bissextile year or not).You may create an if statement for this month.
You can find out if the year is bissextile by using the mod operator an if: the year % 4=! 0 than february has 28 day else you have 29 days. 
Hope this will help you!

Comment: Your method of calculating leap years is wrong, even though a lot of people do that same mistake. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year

Comment: After i saw your comment i read something about :How to determinate if the year is a leap one or not and i find out that this method is valid just for the year before 44 bc (thenks to the Gregorian reform).But that isn't exatly true... At the beginning people did not understand what "once in 4 years" meant, and there was a period (between 45BC and 9BC) where there was a leap year every 3 years. Followed by a period (between 8BC and 8AD) where there was no leapyear at all.

Comment: Yes, but if it is also divisible by 100 it is not. Unless it is also divisible by 400. But it's unimportant since I was already accounting for this. I updated my original post to clarify.

Comment: @Tiberiu Lepadatu I'm not really too worried about previous calendars. I'd rather it just be if our current calendar was extended backwards indefinitely. At least for now.

Comment: I do not understand something:in the wikipedia article says that if the year is divisible with 100 but it is not with 400 that mean that the year is not a leap one but in another wikipedia article says that 1000 was a leap year. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000

Comment: The Gregorian calendar (the current one) was instituted in the 16th century.  Under the Julian calendar which was in effect at 1000, it would have been a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you first and last day of previous month. I used it to set TDateTimePicker component in my application.

```
Word Year, Month, Day;
TDateTime datum_tdatetime = Date();

// first day of actual month
datum_tdatetime.DecodeDate(&year, &month, &day);
day = 1;
datum_tdatetime = EncodeDate(year, month, day);
// last day of previous month
datum_tdatetime -= 1;
// first day of previous month
datum_tdatetime.DecodeDate(&year, &month, &day);
day = 1;
datum_tdatetime = EncodeDate(year, month, day);
```

Comment: What is this for? Please state some helpful information.